# Is there any holomorphic function in a unit ball

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there any holomorphic function in a unit ball such that $f(1/n)=n^{-5/2}$ for $n=2,3,\dots$

Natural candidate is $f(z)=z^{5/2}$ But it isn't holomorphic obviously inside that ball. Can you tell me whatI should check?

Comment: $f(0)=0$ from continuity, so I can use Schwrz lemma yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is such a function, then $g(z)=f(z)^2$ conincides with $z\mapsto z^5$ on a sequence of points converging to $0$. Hence $g(z)=z^5$ for all $z$. If we write $f(z)=z^kh(z)$ with $k\in\mathbb N_0$, $h$ holomorphic, $h(0)\ne0$, we find that $z^{2k}h(z)^2=z^5$, qea.

Comment: Can you post an explicite formula for such a function?

Comment: Such a function $f$ cannot exist, and @Hagen von Eitzen showed how to prove that. Look at the last equation. The left hand side has a zero $z=0$ of even order, but the zero on the right hand side has odd order, which is not possible.

Comment: Ohhh sorry. I get it now! Thanks

Comment: You used here identity theorem yes? But the set where both functions concide needs to be open or im wrong?